# Validation of website on Jqgrid column

Tags: jqgrid

I am new with JqGrid and this is my JqGrid code.  Now I want to make a website validation on column name "website".  If any of you know the answer, kindly reply as soon as possible

```
 {
                            name: 'website',
                            index: 'website',
                            search: false,
                            editable: true
                        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please formulate your question more clear in the future. It's absolutely unclear what you do exactly an what kind of validation you need to implement. If you need for example *client side* validation during editing then [editrules](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editrules) would be the correct way to implement validation. Probably `editrules: {url: true}` or `editrules: {url: true, required: true}` is the property which you need. One uses frequently more common option `editrules: {custom: true, custom_func: function (value, label, name) {...}}`. One need to implement `custom_func` callback function which validate the `value` and returns `[true]` or `[false, "error description"]`. See [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#custom_checking_example).

Comment: thanx oleg for answering.. Its wrking now with editrules:{url:true}    thanx